# Use path of source in a scala script file

Tags: scala, file, path

I am looking for a way to use the full path of the *.scala file that is executed by

```
scala /path/to/file/file.scala
```

The reason is that within my script I would like to use paths, which are relative to the location where file.scala is saved. So, say I want to call /path/to/file/file_second.scala from inside of file.scala while calling file.scala by

```
scala ./to./file/file.scala
```

as the directory I invoked scala from is /path (i.e. what System.getProperty("user.dir") would return). All I know priori is that file_second.scala is in the same directory as file.scala without actually knowing the full path.

I have tried. among others, getClass.getResource("").split(":")(1), but this will either 
return /path/./ or /tmp/scala.tmp/

I guess there must be a clean solution as scala -savecompiled will create a *.jar at exactly that directory I want to work on, but I just cannot figure out how...  :/

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I would like to add a solution I developed from the second answer (when I read it weeks ago, I haven't read answer Nr.1 yet) for scala scripts invoked on linux systems. It is the way I use to do it now. Thanks for all the answers, I learned sooo much from it! I just don't know which answer to flag as "accepted". The solution:

Comment: #! /bin/bash
INSTALL_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "BASH_SOURCE[0]" )" && pwd )"
exec scala -savecompiled -DPARAM_INSTALL_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR "$0" "$@"
!#
val install_dir = System.getProperty("PARAM_INSTALL_DIR") + java.io.File.separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will print it's filesystem path.  Three different approaches are tried in succession, until one of them succeeds.

```
import java.io.File

printf("[%s]\n",new File(getScriptName).getCanonicalPath)
System.exit(0)

def getScriptName:String = {
  // this approach works on the sun jvm:
  val jcmd = System.getProperty("sun.java.command","")
  jcmd.split("""\s+""").toList.reverse.head match {
  case name if new File(name).exists => name
  case _ =>
    // for this to work, you need to set -Dscala.script.name at script launch
    System.getProperty("scala.script.name","") match {
    case name if new File(name).exists => name
    case _ =>
      // last resort: derive script basename from stackdump
      val basename = {
        val filenames = new RuntimeException("").getStackTrace.map { it
          => it.getFileName
        }
        filenames.indexOf("NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java") match {
          case -1 =>  filenames.reverse.head
          case num => filenames(num - 1)
        }
      }
      // then search the system PATH for the script file
      import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      val sep = System.getProperty("path.separator")
      val path = System.getenv("PATH").split(sep)
      path.map(new File(_,basename)).find( _.exists ) match {
        case Some(scriptfile) => scriptfile.getCanonicalPath
        case _ => basename // better than nothing
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The easiest and most portable is the 2nd approach, which depends on use of a wrapper script, as in the following example, for defining Property 'scala.script.name' before calling $SCALA_HOME/bin/scala.  The wrapper script needs to be in your PATH ahead of $SCALA_HOME/bin, of course.  The result is more bulletproof, but is only applicable to scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
for SCRIPT_NAME; do true ; done # set SCRIPT_NAME to the last argument
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dscala.script.name=${SCRIPT_NAME}"
$SCALA_HOME/bin/scala "$@"
```

Use of this wrapper around the scala launcher simplifies usage to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
!#
printf("%s\n",System.getProperty("scala.script.name"))
```

Answer (score 7):

Script preamble:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SCRIPT_PATH=$(readlink -f "$0") && exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
```

Read the value with:

```
val scriptPath = System.getenv("SCRIPT_PATH")
```

Comment: This is the best answer (and as usual it is the last).

Comment: `export SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")" && exec scala "$0" "$@"`

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past in Java.  It's not pretty, and it may not be 100% reliable depending on the details of your class loader situation.

Here is some Scala code that prints out the location of its own class file.

```
import java.net.URL

object LocationTest extends App {
  val classDirURL = LocationTest.getClass.getResource("LocationTest.class")
  val classDirPath = classDirURL.getPath.replaceAll("%20", " ")
  println(classDirPath)
}
```

prints

```
/Users/connor/desktop/LocationTest.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke your program with a param:

```
scala -DPARAM_DIR=tmp Foo
```

and check for the param inside the program:

```
object Foo extends App {
  val dir = System.getProperty ("PARAM_DIR")
  println ("Dir: " + dir) 
}
```

So this wouldn't (necessarily) use the same directory where Foo.scala is located, but it would be flexible, and can be told at runtime where to look for a class.

In normal cases you either bundle classes in a Jar, or you set a common classpath, and then you might have a package which is resolved relatively to the classpath:

For a class to.file.File in

```
 /path/to/file/file.scala
```

it would be the classpath /path, for a class File in a package `file` it would be /path/to/.

If your classpath is /path/to/file, the second class should be reachable simply by name.